# Watir-Webdriver not running with Jruby 1.7.2

Tags: ruby, jruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to run my watir-webdriver scripts with jruby 1.7.2.

We have a windows8 VM running jenkins and executing our scripts.  I have a suite of them that won't run when I build them through Jenkins.

I noticed when I used my Windows7 VM and selected jruby 1.7.2 as the SDK in rubymine.  It starts but nothing else happens.  No errors.  When I change the SDK to ruby 1.9.3 it works fine.

I am not sure how to resolve this or where to start investigating.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay I found the answer. It was located here and they are now working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983307/jruby-watir-is-hanging-when-launching-browser