# jruby1.6.7+watir+cucumer1.2.1 on win7 can not open ff14.0.1

Tags: windows-7, webdriver, jruby, watir-webdriver

I installed jruby1.6.7 on win7 and firefox 14.0.1 and run jruby -v is ok
and installed below plugin:

```
jgem install activerecord -v='3.0.5'
jgem install activerecord-jdbc-adapter -v='1.1.3'
jgem install arel -v='2.2.1'
jgem install color -v='1.4.1'
jgem install rspec -v='2.6.0'
jgem install cucumber -v='1.2.1'
jgem install i18n -v='0.6.0'
jgem install jruby-openssl -v='0.7.4'
jgem install rack -v='1.3.2'
jgem install rest-open-uri -v='1.0.0'
jgem install watir-webdriver
jgem install ruby-debug
```

then i run this script :

```
require "rubygems";require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
browser.goto "http://www.google.com/"
puts browser.url
browser.a(:text => "Google.com in English").click
browser.a(:text => "Images").click
puts browser.title
browser.text_field(:name => "q").set "book"
browser.button(:value => "Search Images").click
puts browser.images.size
browser.close
```

the firefox not open and there is no error message!
but it worked when i do that on windowsxp

Comment: these message play on the cmd  C:\Users\Administrator>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "rubygems";require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
-

Comment: Why such an old firefox?   The current general release is 21, the current Extended Support Release (ESR) is 17 (http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all.html).   Typically we have our automation testbeds use the ESR which is updated about once a year.. and use the current general release on people's desktops.  (less hassle of continuously updating testbeds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JRuby: Watir is hanging when launching browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983307/jruby-watir-is-hanging-when-launching-browser)

Solution is to add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to JAVA_OPTS telling Java to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 when possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you installed the latest version of watir-webdriver, which would pull the latest version of selenium-webdriver. Given that you are running a very old version of Firefox, it is possible that there is an incompatibility between webdriver and Firefox.

Try one of the following:

1. Upgrading Firefox to the latest version.
2. Downgrading selenium-webdriver to an older version. Try the same version that you successfully used on the the WinXP Firefox 14 machine.